# Root element is missing Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I need to read a xml file, but I have this error when try to read it.

```
public void load()
{
  IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
  IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream;
  try
  {
    fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("sites.xml", FileMode.Open, 
      FileAccess.Read);
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile("sites.xml");
    XDocument sites= new XDocument(new XElement("root"));
    fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("sites.xml", FileMode.Open, 
      FileAccess.Read);
  }          

  List<Site> listSites= new List<Site>();

  using (StreamReader file= new StreamReader(fileStream))
  {
    XDocument doc= XDocument.Load(file);

    foreach (XElement elemento in doc.Elements())
    {
      String name= elemento.Element("name").Value;
      String url = elemento.Element("url").Value;
      listSites.Add(new Site(name));
    }
    lstSites.ItemsSource = listSites;
  }
}
```

On the line

```
XDocument doc= XDocument.Load(file);
```

I receive the error in the subject. Can you help me ?

Comment: +1. Well done question. Please learn to use the code formatting when asking questions, though. :) You can format code in a few ways... Paste in your code, select it all, and press Ctrl+K, or click the `{}` button on the editor toolbar, or simply indent each line four or more spaces. You can preview it below the editor to make sure the formatting is proper before you post the question. :)

Comment: Have you checked if there is anything in your 'file' object. You could for example check it by setting a breakpoint on the line XDocument doc= XDocument.Load(file) and use the Immediate window to call file.ReadToEnd()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should change the way you are working with xml files and isolated storage. you could create a Site class containing your name and url properties and serialize a list of these to the isolated storage.

an example can be found here:
http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-XML-files

Answer (score 1):

Your document (sites.xml) is supposed to have a root element, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MyRootElement>
...
</MyRootElement>
```

Comment: I am trying to add a root here 

XDocument sites= new XDocument(new XElement("root"));

but don't work